# Android Get phone number hint

Tags: android, phone-number

I have been referring so my tutorial links to get the phone number hint but the code which is used has been deprecated.

```
val hintRequest = HintRequest.Builder()
            .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
            .build()
```

This is the one which I am following right now.

https://developers.google.com/identity/phone-number-hint/android#retrieve-phone-number

```
ActivityResultLauncher phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher =
  registerForActivityResult(
      new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
      new ActivityResultCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
              try {
                  String phoneNumber = Identity.getSignInClient(activity).getPhoneNumberFromIntent(result.getData());
              } catch {
                  Log.e(TAG, “Phone Number Hint failed”, e);
              }
          }
  });
```

For the above code I get the error in android studio

```
Class 'Anonymous class derived from ActivityResultCallback' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onActivityResult(O)' in 'ActivityResultCallback'
```

What is the correct way to implement Phone Number Hint ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code if you are using java,
first make an ActivityResultLauncher like this:

```
    ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                            try {
                                String phoneNumber = Identity.getSignInClient(getApplicationContext()).getPhoneNumberFromIntent(result.getData());
                                showPhoneNum.setText(phoneNumber);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
                });
```

then make a GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest object and follow this code:

```
    GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest request = GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest.builder().build();

        Identity.getSignInClient(MainActivity.this)
                .getPhoneNumberHintIntent(request)
                .addOnSuccessListener(result -> {
                    try {
                        IntentSender intentSender = result.getIntentSender();
                        phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher.launch(new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intentSender).build());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.i("Error launching", "error occurred in launching Activity result");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.i("Failure occurred", "Failure getting phone number"));
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: I am always getting ->"Phone Number Hint failed" it goes in addOnFailureListener { (Log.e("TAG", "Phone Number Hint failed")) }. Tried on different android OS level's

Comment: onFailure can be called on certain use cases, so if you can elaborate on your use case maybe i can help.

Comment: it says -> 16: No phone number is found on this device. Even though the device has valid numbers available.

Comment: If user has not set the phone number on that particular device then it will show this error. You can verify it by going to settings -> about -> status, there you will find a Basic info section if which is empty will give you following error. so first update that and then check it.

Comment: I am always getting +191 and then mobile number is anybody else getting this? is it a issue or regex?